# Woocommerce - How to persist my own custom form on my own custom page at My Account area?

Tags: php, woocommerce, crud

I found a lot of tutorials explaning how to create a custom tab in MyAccount Area. And using that I have created my custom page in Woocommerce My Account.

But, after some hours of research in the internet I don't found a solution to make a CRUD to this custom page.

Sorry, I'm a designer trying to make some coding. (but trying! :)

Can you save me?

The code of my custom tab (page) is:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_account_new_endpoints' );

function my_account_new_endpoints() {
  add_rewrite_endpoint( 'fit', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
  add_rewrite_endpoint( 'services', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}



add_action( 'woocommerce_account_fit_endpoint', 'fit_endpoint_content' );

function fit_endpoint_content() { 
    // Into this page I have my own form
    get_template_part('page-templates/my-account-fit'); 
}



add_action( 'woocommerce_account_services_endpoint', 'services_endpoint_content' );

function services_endpoint_content(){ 
  get_template_part('page-templates/my-account-services'); 
}



add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_account_menu_order' );

function my_account_menu_order(){

   $menuOrder = array(
    'dashboard'         => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' ),
    'orders'            => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
    'fit'               => __( 'Fit', 'woocommerce' ),
    'services'          => __( 'Services', 'woocommerce' ),
    'edit-address'      => __( 'Addresses', 'woocommerce' ),
    'edit-account'      => __( 'Details', 'woocommerce' ),
    'support'           => __( 'Support', 'woocommerce' ),
    'customer-logout'   => __( 'Exit', 'woocommerce' ),
   );
   return $menuOrder;
}



add_filter("woocommerce_get_query_vars", function ($vars) {

  foreach (["support", "services", "fit"] as $e) { 
    $vars[$e] = $e; 
  }

  return $vars;
});
```